# Resolve Restangular.get in factory constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm using Restangular to manage access to my RESTful backend in my Angular application. The call below gets me all the results in my backend.

```
Restangular.all('results').getList().then(function(results) {
   $scope.results = results;
});
```

I have made use of the extendModel() function to add prototype functions to some of my backend models, so before my results are returned to me they run through this function.

```
Restangular.extendModel('results', function(model) {
                var result = new Result(model);               
                return result;
            });
```

My results factory looks like this

```
angular.module('RankingsApp')
    .factory('Result', function(Extender, Restangular, $rootScope) {

        function Result(model) {                
            angular.extend(this, model);
             Restangular.one('fencers', this.links.fencer).get().then(function(response) {
                this.fencer = response;
            });
        };

        Result.prototype.Fencer = function() {
            return this.fencer;
        };       

        return Result;
    });
```

One of the functions that I've added to a Result is to return the the Fencer associated with the result. However when I make the async call from inside my Results constructor, value seems to be set. My assumption is that this is because of the async nature of the call, but I'm at a loss currently as to how I would go about actually fixing it.

The Fencer function is used within my UI to display some additional information

```
<tr ng-repeat='result in results'>                    
    <td>{{result.Fencer().name}}</td>                   
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your UI depends on the data, I would use a [deferred promise](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#style-y081) in your module's resolve configuration to grab the data handle the user conditionally afterward, i.e. success or failure.

simple example of deferred promise:

```
function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('fencer', {
        url: '/fencer/result',
        controller: 'FencerCtrl',
        resolve: {
            resultService: function getFencerResult($q, dataservice, sessionService) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var myData = {};
                myData = dataservice.getFormDefaults();
                deferred.resolve(myData);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Updated controller code:**

```
Restangular.all('results').getList().then(function(results) {

   $scope.apply( function(){
        $scope.results = results;
    });
});
```

**Wait for controller to update from resource**

[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) is used for spinning icon

```
<tr ng-repeat='result in results'>                    
    <td ng-show="results.length < 1"> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Loading</td>
    <td ng-show="results.length>0">{{result.Fencer().name}}</td>                   
</tr>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with how I'm getting my initial list of results from the backend, and added a but more description as to how the flow of my application works.

Comment: Sure. I updated my answer with your controller code. Give that a run. It seems like your digest cycle isn't being triggered until another event happens, delaying the update to your view.

Comment: Wrapping the call in $scope.$apply() triggers an "Action Already In Progress error"

Comment: Hmm.. the alternative is to allow your UI to handle waiting for the resource

Comment: Ah, i think we're on different paths atm, I'm able to get the results back without issue. My problem is that  after I get the Result, I pass it into a Factory and within the Factory I'm making another call to the backend and try to attach it the the original result. I probably could have worded it better. I'll see if I can refactor my original question

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out a way to get this to work. In my original constructor I set the fencer

```
function Result(model) {                
            angular.extend(this, model);
             Restangular.one('fencers', this.links.fencer).get().then(function(response) {
                this.fencer = response;
            });
        };
```

To get this to resolve however I needed to create a setter function which I attached to my already existing Fencer().

```
Result.prototype.Fencer = function(fencer) {
    if(fencer)
    {
        this.fencer = fencer;
    }
    return this.fencer;
};
```